# Как передать ссылку на объект в другой Activity для изменений

Tags: java, android, activity

Клал объект, наследующий интерфейс Serializable `intent.putExtra(Task.KEY_TASK, task);` и доставал `Task task = (Task) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Task.KEY_TASK);`, но последующие изменения объекта не влияли на изначальный.

Comment: Вам необходимо зайти в активность, получить данные и вернуться с ними обратно? Для этого есть `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Спасибо, тема закрыта

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы передаёте объект через `putExtra`, вы по сути сначала вытаскиваете данные из объекта, а потом передаёте их и из них соберётся новый объект, это называется сериализация и десериализация.

Чтобы была возможность управлять одним и тем же объектом, вам нужно хранить его в таком месте, где он будет доступен для всех `Activity`. Самый простой вариант это паттерн одиночка (singleton).

```
public class Singleton { 
    private static Singleton instance; 

    private Singleton (){ 
    } 

    public static Singleton getInstance(){ 
        if (null == instance){ 
           instance = new Singleton(); 
        } 
        return instance; 
    } 
}
```

Чтобы воспользоваться им, просто вызовите метод `Singleton.getInstance();` он везде вернёт ссылку на единственный объект в системе.